# Is C read() Thread Safe?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, file, thread-safety

I'm writing a program where multiple threads might read from a file simultaneously. No threads are writing to the file, but they might each copy its contents to separate memory segments.

To do implement this, I'm required to use an API that gives me a file descriptor for the file I want to read. I'm reading chunks of the file with C's [`read`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) function. The man page says that, "On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file), and the file position is advanced by this number." I can't find any definitive information, though, on whether or not the advancement of the file position is thread safe.

Say I have thread T1 and thread T2 reading 1 byte of the file at a time. If `read()` is thread-safe, I would expect the following:

```
T1: read() => file position == 1
T2: read() => file position == 1
T1: read() => file position == 2
T2: read() => file position == 2
...
```

But I'm worried that if it's *not* thread-safe, then the following could happen:

```
T1: read() => file position == 1
T2: read() => file position == 2
T1: read() => file position == 3
T2: read() => file position == 4
...
```

If it helps, each thread would be using the same file descriptor. In other words, it's the API that opens the file using `open()`. The threads that are reading the file then fetch that file descriptor based on a client request. If each thread stores its own information about the file position, then it should be fine. I just can't find any information on what holds the file position, and where `read()` figures out what it is.

Comment: The [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) also says that `read` should be "atomic with respect to each other in the effects specified in POSIX.1-2008 when they operate on regular files or symbolic links" (with some caveats depending on Linux version).

Comment: Thanks for the link! That wasn't in my local man page for read or in any of my go-to sources. Very helpful!

Comment: Oh by the way, if you want to read more about the POSIX standard, or use it as a reference, [please see this link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`read` itself is thread-safe, but that doesn't necessarily mean the things you want to do with it are thread-safe. Per POSIX ([2.9.7 Thread Interactions with Regular File Operations](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_07)):

> All of the following functions shall be atomic with respect to each other in the effects specified in POSIX.1-2008 when they operate on regular files or symbolic links:
>
> ...

(`read` is in the list that follows.)

Among other things, this means that reading the data and advancing the current file position are atomic with respect to each other, and each byte that's read will be read exactly once. However, there are other considerations that can complicate things for you, especially:

- Short reads: `read(fd, buf, n)` need not read `n` bytes. It could read anywhere between 1 and `n` bytes, and when you call it again to read the remainder, that second read is no longer atomic with respect to the first one.
- Other file types: POSIX only guarantees atomicity of `read` for regular files and perhaps a few other types. Specific systems like Linux *probably* have stronger guarantees, but I would be cautious.

It may be preferable to use the `pread` function (where you can specify a file offset to read from *without* having to seek to that position, and where the resulting file position remains unchanged) or perform locking around your file accesses to avoid such problems.

Comment: Perfect! Didn't know about `pread`. The threads are incrementally storing how many bytes they've read, so I'll have the offset handy. That'll do the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Note [read](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html):

> The `read()` function shall attempt to read `nbyte` bytes from the file associated with the open file descriptor, `fildes`, into the buffer pointed to by `buf`. ***The behavior of multiple concurrent reads on the same pipe, FIFO, or terminal device is unspecified.*** (emphasis mine)

From the same reference:

> ```
> ssize_t pread(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte, off_t offset);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The `pread()` function shall be equivalent to `read()`, except that it shall read from a given position in the file without changing the file pointer. The first three arguments to `pread()` are the same as `read()` with the addition of a fourth argument offset for the desired position inside the file. An attempt to perform a `pread()` on a file that is incapable of seeking shall result in an error.

Each thread can keep track of its own `offset`, and specify it.

Comment: `ftell` and `fseek` are `stdio` functions and have nothing to do with `read` and file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of thread safety is incorrect or you are misapplying it.

```
T1: read() => file position == 1
T2: read() => file position == 1
T1: read() => file position == 2
T2: read() => file position == 2
...
```

Here, we have T1 and T2 invoking `read` at the same time and we get a result that could not possibly occur regardless of which order the `read` operations take place in. This is the canonical example of a race occurring when a function is *not* thread safe.

Roughly speaking, a function is thread safe if invoking it concurrently produces sane results, equivalent to those you get when you invoke it non-concurrently. If a single thread calling `read` never processes the same data twice, then `read` is thread safe if two threads calling it also never process the same data twice.