# is there an official document that mark read/write function as thread-safe functions?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, system-calls

the man pages of read/write didn't mention anything about their thread-safety

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17432052/10813146)!
i understood this functions are thread safe but in this comment there is not a link to an official document.

In other hand according to this [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html)!    which says:

```
The read() function shall attempt to read nbyte bytes
from the file associated with the open file descriptor,
fildes, into the buffer pointed to by buf.
The behavior of multiple concurrent reads on the same pipe, FIFO, or 
terminal device is unspecified.
```

I concluded the read function is not thread safe.

I am so confused now. please send me a link to official document about thread-safety of this functions.

i tested this functions with pipe but there wasn't any problem.(of course i know i couldn't state any certain result by testing some example)

thanks in advance:)

Comment: Unless explicitly stated as thread safe, most functions aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread safe versions of `read` and `write` are `pread` and `pwrite`:

[pread(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html)

```
   The pread() and pwrite() system calls are especially useful in
   multithreaded applications.  They allow multiple threads to perform
   I/O on the same file descriptor without being affected by changes to
   the file offset by other threads.
```

when two threads write() at the same time the order is not specified (which write call completes first) therefore the behaviour is unspecified (without synchronization)

Comment: yup, i know pread() and pwrite() are thread-safe but what about read/write functions?

Comment: You have a nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29331931/1606345) here, in theory yes: read itself is thread-safe, but that doesn't necessarily mean the things you want to do with it are thread-safe

Comment: but in the same [reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) have been mentioned:  "the behavior is unspecified".
which one is correct?

Comment: Yes, when two thread write()s at the same time the order is not specified (which write call completes first)  therefore the behaviour is unspecified (without synchronization)

Comment: oh my god:)) so it mean's the order of calling functions
thank you very much.

Comment: @milad ... yep ;)

Answer (score 1):

`read()` and `write()` are not strictly thread-safe, and there is no documentation that says they are, as the location where the data is read from or written to can be modified by another thread.

Per [the POSIX `read` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) (note the bolded parts):

> The `read()` function shall attempt to read `nbyte` bytes from the file associated with the open file descriptor, `fildes`, into the buffer pointed to by `buf`. **The behavior of multiple concurrent reads on the same pipe, FIFO, or terminal device is unspecified**.

That's the part you noticed - but that does not cover all possible types of file descriptors, such as regular files. It only applies to "pipe[s], FIFO[s]" and "terminal device[s]".  This part covers almost everything else (weird things like "files" in `/proc` that are generated on the fly by the kernel are, well, weird and highly implementation-specific):

> On files that support seeking (for example, a regular file), **the `read()` shall start at a position in the file given by the file offset associated with `fildes`**. The file offset shall be incremented by the number of bytes actually read.

Since the "file offset associated with `fildes`" is subject to modification from other threads in the process, the following code is not guaranteed to return the same results even given the exact same file contents and inputs for `fd`, `offset`, `buffer`, and `bytes`:

```
lseek( fd, offset, SEEK_SET );
read( fd, buffer, bytes );
```

Since both `read()` and `write()` depend upon a state (current file offset) that can be modified at any moment by another thread, they are not tread-safe.

Comment: Note that the POSIX standard in [2.9.7 Thread Interactions with Regular File Operations](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_07) states that operations on *regular files* (including `read()` and `write()` are specified to be atomic WRT each other.

Comment: sorry i am yet a bit confused. i just wonder about reading and writing in pipes and FIFO[s]. i think the bolded part state that: reading from pipe is not atomic. am i right?
or in other word i didn't know it's exact mean. "the atomicity is unspecified or the order of executing"?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield While `read()` and `write()` operations themselves may be atomic, there's no way to guarantee the current offset remains unchanged in a multithreaded process, so there's no way to ensure where the data comes from or winds up in the file. Since both `read()` and `write()` depend upon and also modify a state that impacts all threads, they're not multithread safe.

Comment: @milad For FIFOs, pipes, and terminal devices, POSIX merely doesn't specify what the system does and allows different implementation to specify their own behavior. POSIX does require that `read()` and `write()` operations on pipes and FIFOs up to `PIPE_BUF` bytes be atomic: "Write requests of {PIPE_BUF} bytes or less shall not be interleaved with data from other processes doing writes on the same pipe. Writes of greater than `PIPE_BUF` bytes may have data interleaved, on arbitrary boundaries, with writes by other processes, whether or not the `O_NONBLOCK` flag of the file status flags is set."

Answer (score 0):

On some embedded file systems, or really old desktop systems that weren't designed to facilitate multitasking support (e.g. MS-DOS 3.0), an attempt to perform an `fread()` on one file while an `fread()` is being performed on another file may result in arbitrary system corruption.

Any modern operating system and language runtime will guarantee that such corruption won't occur as a result of operations performed on unrelated files, or when independent file descriptors are used to access the same file in ways that do not modify it.  Functions like `fread()` and `fwrite()` will be thread-safe *when used in that fashion*.

The act of reading data from a disk file does not modify it, but reading data from many kinds of stream will modify them by removing data.  If two threads both perform actions that modify the same stream, such actions may interfere with each other in unspecified ways even if such modifications are performed by `fread()` operations.